# Convert mega menu drop down to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css, drop-down-menu

i'm developing a new wordpress theme and want to create a mega drop down menu, so how

can i added the sub-menu and mega-menu classes to the menu with wordpress

all classes started with 'anime' represent a separate animation type

'dropa' class is for drop down menu (not mega menu).
'mega-dropa' class is for mega menu only.

```
<div class="navi">
          <nav class="navbar-right">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropodown"><button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button><a href="index.html">Home</a> 
                <ul class="dropadown dromobile dropa anime-rotate-scale">
                  <li>Choose your homepage style<hr></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class ="fa fa-home"></i>   <a href="index-2.html" title="">Home-2</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="index-3.html" title="">Home-3</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="index-4.html" title="">Home-4</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href="index-5.html" title="">Home-5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropodown raw"><button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button><a href="products.html">Products</a> 
                <ul class="dropadown dromobile mega-drop-liste mega-dropa anime-scale">
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Website developpement</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-html5"></i>Html5</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-css3"></i>Css3</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-joomla"></i>Javascripy</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>jQuery</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Mobile app developpement</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-windows"></i>Node Js</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>Backbone</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-android"></i>Android developpement</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-apple"></i>iOs developpement</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Photoshop & Illustrator</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Images retouching</li>
                      <li>Vector icons design</li>
                      <li>Logo and Brand design</li>
                      <li>Wallpaper and Background</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">3d Max & Maya</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Html5</li>
                      <li>Css3</li>
                      <li>Tutorial</li>
                      <li>Snippets</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">h3Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/iphone1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/iphone1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/iphone1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/iphone1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropodown"><button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button><a href="about-us.html">About us</a>
                <ul class="dropadown dromobile mega-drop-liste mega-dropa anime-rotate-3d">
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Html5</li>
                      <li>Css3</li>
                      <li>Tutorial</li>
                      <li>Snippets</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Html5 & Css3</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Html5</li>
                      <li>Css3</li>
                      <li>Tutorial</li>
                      <li>Snippets</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">Photoshop & Illustrator</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Html5</li>
                      <li>Css3</li>
                      <li>Tutorial</li>
                      <li>Snippets</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><a href="#">3d Max & Maya</a><hr>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Html5</li>
                      <li>Css3</li>
                      <li>Tutorial</li>
                      <li>Snippets</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropodown"><button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                <ul class="dropadown dromobile dropa anime-scale">
                  <li>Choose your portflio style<hr></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class ="fa fa-print"></i> Portfolio-4-columns</li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Portfolio-3-columns</li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Portfolio-2-columns</li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Portfolio-mixed-columns</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropodown"><button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                <ul class="dropadown dromobile dropa anime-rotate-3d">
                  <li>Choose your portflio style<hr></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class ="fa fa-print"></i><a href="portfolio-1.html">Portfolio-1</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i><a href="portfolio-2.html">Portfolio-2</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-th"></i><a href="portfolio-3.html">Portfolio-3</a></li>
                  <li class="col-xs-12 col-ms-6"><i class="fa fa-book"></i><a href="portfolio-4.html">Portfolio-4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want just to convert this mega menu to wordpress menu

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it would be better to create your own custom menu using `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` for such a customized menu , have a look at this link below , there is also an example in it, may be it could help you out.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items